# Pass parameters from view with Spring Security in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, gsp

I want to send parameters from view to the controller action, which protected by Spring Security, in my case user isn't authorized in Spring Security.
For example, this is my gsp-view:

```
<g:form class="form-signin" controller="VisitorSpace">
  <joda:timePicker name="startTime" value="${new LocalTime()}" precision="minute"/>
  <g:hiddenField name="cafeeName" value="${cafeeName.cafeeName}" />
  <g:actionSubmit value="Reserve"  action="makeReserve" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Reserve</g:actionSubmit>
</g:form>
```

Parameters pass perfect to action, if it isn't protected by Spring Security. But it's impossible pass parameters to action, which is protected by Spring Security.
I noticed, when I pass parameters via params-attribute in view, I can pass parameter from the hidden field. I try to pass all parameters via hidden fields, but I get only an one parameter. What's wrong?